# 500 Server Error after User Signup Through Google App Engine using hotmail account

Tags: google-app-engine

I have an application deployed to Google App Engine.

The application relies on App Engine User API to login and signup.  However I noticed that if user signup using hotmail account, after verify the account through OpenID option.  App Engine tries to direct the browser to the following URL: https://appengine.google.com/_ah/conflogin?continue=https://myappid.appspot.com/login.do, where /login.do is used in UserService.createLoginURL("/login.do") to create the login URL.

At this step I am getting 500 Server Error as the following.  When I check my server log, I couldn't find any request to login.do.  Please help.

Error: Server Error

The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
If the problem persists, please report your problem and mention this error message and the query that caused it.

Comment: I got this error also sometimes when I try to login with the google account

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when logging in 4 accounts.
It works on logging in 3 accounts.

We can not control the number of accounts a user login at the same time.
I think it is a critical bug in the implementation of Google.

Conclusion, Users API is not usable. The only way is to use OAuth.